# Array does not store values correctly

Tags: java, arrays

i have the following problem I cannot understand by my own.
I created a very very simple hash function and I want to store each 
value into an array, however no matter what array I print [9], [10], [11] 
they all store the same value but when I print hashing(text) I get different values for each line which I want to store obviously in each array

```
int [] hashes = new int [1000];

try {
    File file = new File (path);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        text = inputFile.nextLine();
        text = hashing(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hashes [i] = Integer.parseInt(text);
        }
        System.out.println (text);
        System.out.println ("####");
        System.out.println (hashes[10]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line you are reading from the file, you are assigning all the elements of the array.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
int[] hashes = new int[1000];

File file = new File(path);
try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file)) {
    for (int i = 0; inputFile.hasNextLine() && i < hashes.length; i++) {
        text = inputFile.nextLine();
        text = hashing(text);

        hashes[i] = Integer.parseInt(text);
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println("####");
        System.out.println(hashes[10]);
    }
}
```

(Also tidied up the resource handling and formatting.)